# Why am I getting apparmor error messages in the syslog about NTP and LDAP?

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, ntp, apparmor

On my newly installed Ubuntu 12.04 machine, with `ntp` and `slapd` installed, the following messages appear in `/var/log/syslog` at regular intervals:

> *Feb 23 18:54:07 my-host kernel: [   24.610703] type=1400 audit(1393181647.872:15): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/ntpd" name="/etc/ldap/ldap.conf" pid=1526 comm="ntpd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0*

I've searched, but can't find any info on what may be causing these messages and how to fix the problem. Can anyone shed any light on what's causing this and what to do about it?

Answer (score 25):

This is what it is telling you:

- `apparmor="DENIED"` AppArmor denied something based on a profile (we'll get to that later).
- `operation="open"` The operation AppArmor denied (in this case opening something, probably a file).
- `profile="/usr/sbin/ntpd"` The profile that made AppArmor deny this action.
- `name="/etc/ldap/ldap.conf"` The file that something was trying to open.
- `pid=1526` The PID of the process trying to open it.
- `comm="ntpd"` The command/name of the process that tried to open it.
- `requested_mask="r"` What ntpd wanted to do with the file (`r` for read in this case).
- `denied_mask="r"` What AppArmor stopped it from doing.

So, in plain English, ntpd wanted to read LDAP's config file, AppArmor thought it had no business in LDAP's config file, so it blocked the action according to ntpd's profile for `/usr/sbin/ntpd`.

If you haven't been tinkering with NTP to make it want to read LDAP's config file, and haven't been tinkering with NTP's AppArmor profile *and* this isn't causing you problems, you shouldn't need to take any action.

Why is AppArmor even there in first place? AppArmor's main purpose is to prevent compromised apps/processes from doing things they shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive response. I haven't touched NTP, apart from `apt-get`'ing it. Any idea how I can stop NTP attempting to read the LDAP config and producing the error messages in the log?

Comment: @Lorax I'm pretty sure the only way to stop the message would be to disable ntpd's profile in AppArmor, which isn't a good idea. It isn't a problem, so I wouldn't be worried about it. Or you could tell AppArmor to log things differently.

Comment: "ntpd wanted to read LDAP's config file, AppArmor thought it had no business in LDAP's config file, so it blocked the action" ... I thought that was what `chown/chmod` were for.  If you want to keep `ntp` out of `ldap`'s business, then don't make `/etc/ldap/` readable to user `ntp`. It's sad that this has become yet another bloated unwieldy nuisance that we have to Google `Ubuntu disable apparmor`.  Small problems rarely warrant big solutions.

Comment: Since the OP's system has a LDAP server (`slapd`) installed, it might also have `ldap` on one or more lines in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. That would make glibc's resolver library component prepare for resolving names from a LDAP directory, which would explain the access attempt. The fact that every process that needs names resolved would have to have their own LDAP connection is not ideal, and explains why modern solutions like `sssd` were developed.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by Seth](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116746/258991) already covers how to interpret the message and the direct cause.

But the root cause might be that you have installed and configured `libnss-ldap` but have not told AppArmor about it.

Ubuntu 12.04 is old enough to have `libnss-ldap`, which has no separate service for sending LDAP queries out to the server(s); instead, it makes *every process that uses `glibc`* have its own LDAP connection if they need LDAP-based name resolution services, according to `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

This is very inconvenient when using extra access control like AppArmor, because you'll effectively have to allow *every process* to access the LDAP client configuration and to make outgoing LDAP connections. And that is probably one of the reasons why `libnss-ldap` fell out of favor and was replaced by `libnss-ldapd`, which centralizes the job of making outgoing LDAP connections for name resolution to a dedicated service process. Unfortunately Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is old enough to not have had that package.

The default `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/nameservice` file already includes the line:

```
#include <abstractions/ldapclient>
```

which should have covered the files required by `libnss-ldap`.

Unfortunately, the `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/ldapclient` file that is referred to by this line was adopted to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS unmodified from SuSE, and Ubuntu has slightly different paths for LDAP client configuration files. You would have to modify that file first to change the line

```
  /etc/ldap.conf            r,
```

to

```
  /etc/ldap/ldap.conf       r,
```

and similarly fix any other path referred to in the file to match actual Ubuntu file locations too.

After that, you would have to either reboot the system or use a command like

```
sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.ntpd
```

to refresh each AppArmor profile that is currently loaded (see `sudo aa-status` for the list of loaded profiles).

Answer (score -1):

Seems this is a simple permission issue, by assigning the right permission/ownership will solve this issue.

```
Mar 15 12:15:45 user-sys kernel: [  673.423996] audit: type=1400 audit(1552632345.954:91): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/home/path/path1/file.html" pid=4949 comm=46532042726F6B65722035313639 requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
```

Fixed this with chown command:

e.g.: `chown user:user file.html`

Before it was `-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  37K Mar 14 20:47 file.html`, 
so Firefox interface shows the below warning, this might be Firefox browser limitations since it works on Chromium browser.

```
Access to the file was denied
The file at /home/path/path1/file.html is not readable.
It may have been removed, moved, or file permissions may be preventing access."
```

Comment: the deny is because of apparmor, not because there is a lack of access right to the files. If apparmor has no configuration directives that allow access, then it deny it, regardless of the right that the file has.